# Sort asynchronously with external source

Tags: typescript, sorting, asynchronous, async-await, github-api

I want to sort my Github Repos by Clones in Typescript
The equivalence in plain js would be

```js
repos.sort(async (a, b) => {
  (await insights.traffic.clones(user, b.name, username, password)).uniques -
    (await insights.traffic.clones(user, a.name, username, password)).uniques;
});
```

But [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) doesn't work with async/await

`repos` is [`https://api.github.com/users/<user>/repos`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user)
`insights` is [`import * as insights from 'github-insights'`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-insights) [Docs for clones](https://kaaax0815.github.io/github-insights/classes/api.traffic.html#clones)

This would sort the repos in descending order be unique clones

It would get every repo for my account and then sort it with [`https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/traffic/clones`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-clones)

Is there any way to make it work?

Using [fast-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-sort)
I came up with this

```js
const sorted = sort(repos).desc([
  async (u) => await (await insights.traffic.clones(user, u.name, username, password)).uniques
]);
```

but this doesn't sort at all, it just is `repos`

Comment: Try getting all information *first*, throw it in an array and _then_ sort.

Comment: What Evert said. The sort delegate is called multiple times per element, so you wouldn't want an `async` sort delegate anyway.

Comment: @Evert But then I would have to manually manage a connection between all the repos and corresponding clones and have to fetch it for every repo. is there any efficient and convient way?

Comment: @kaaaxcreators if by 'manually manage a connection' you mean create a simple data structure using arrays, then yes.. do this. This is the simple way. I'll leave this as pseudo code as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting all information first, throw it in an array and then sort.

Pseudo-ish code:

```js
async function getClonesForRepo(repo) {
 // Do your thing and return a number
}

const repoClones = new Map();
for(const repo of repos) {
  repoClones.set(repo.name, await getClonesForRepo(repo));
}

const sorted = repos.sort(
  (a, b) => repoClones.get(a.name) - repoClones.get(b.name)
);
```

Comment: The Map and therefore the sorted array has a lenght of 0

Comment: if the map is empty, then `repos` was empty.

Comment: my mistake, i did some stuff wrong. then i checked the repo lenght and you were right. i did a filter wrong. thank you very much